# Как добавить массив в пользовательский инспектор?

Tags: c#, unity3d

есть у меня в скрипте массив с спрайтами. я решил сделать кастомный инспектор и не знаю как заново отрисовать этот массив не используя base.OnInspectorGUI(), так как оно занято уже.

есть ли легкий способ как отрисовать массив в кастомном инспекторе ?

```
   public Sprite[] anim;
```

```
   Activator unit = target as Activator;
   unit.anim = EditorGUILayout ??? ;
```

или еще такой вариант.
как написать свой кастомный массив чтобы он был равен изначальному массиву в скрипте по значениям ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Документация [Custom Editors](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/editor-CustomEditors.html)

```
public class LookAtPointEditor : Editor 
{
    private SerializedProperty _anim;
    
    private void OnEnable ()
    {
        _anim = serializedObject.FindProperty("anim");
    }

    public override void OnInspectorGUI ()
    {
        serializedObject.Update();
        EditorGUILayout.PropertyField(_anim);
        serializedObject.ApplyModifiedProperties();
    }
}
```